# Buttons inside a cell of table view

Tags: swift, uitableview

In a tableview cell i need two buttons one for accept one for decline.

In UITableViewCell i have connected the IBOutlet for both buttons. 
In xcode, I have set decline tag to 2 and accept tag to 3.

Inside the ViewController

```
  func accept(_ sender: UIButton){
   let buttonTag = sender.tag
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: friendRequestTableView as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = followerReqTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let user = requestsArray[indexPath.row]

  func decline(_ sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: friendRequestTableView as UIView)
    let indexPath: IndexPath! = followerReqTableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    let user = requestsArray[indexPath.row]

}


func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = friendRequestTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendRequestTableViewCell") as? FriendRequestTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


    let user = requestsArray[indexPath.row]

    let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView



    cell.confCell(///some user details)

    cell.decline.tag = 2
    cell.accept.tag = 3

    cell.decline.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.decline(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.decline.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.accept(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    return cell

}
```

When i tap on decline it calls both functions- decline and accept, when i tap on accept it does nothing.
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Of course it does: You add both actions to the same button, twice `cell.decline.addTarget`.

Comment: beat me too it @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite normal because you add decline and accept actions to the same button on those two lines of code :

```
cell.decline.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.decline(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.decline.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.accept(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Just replace with :

```
cell.decline.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.decline(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.accept.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.accept(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

To associate decline function with your decline button and your accept function to your accept button.

Comment: i really need to sleep more... :D thanks guys!  question: do i need to have the tags set inside the cellForRowAt if i have the set via xcode?